# Prove that $T_{1}, T_{2}-T_{1}, \dots$ are independent

Tags: probability, independence

Let $X_{n}$ be a sequence of independent random variables following a Bernoulli distribution of parameter $p$.

We define $T_{0} = 0$ and
 $\forall n \geq 1,$ $$T_{n} = \inf \lbrace k > T_{n-1} ; X_{k} = 1 \rbrace$$ or $T_{n} = \infty$ if the infimum is not finite.

I'm trying to prove that $T_{1}, T_{2}-T_{1}, \dots, T_{n}-T_{n-1}$ are independent.

Let $(k_{1}, \dots, k_{n}) \in \mathbb{N}^{n}$ ; I have shown that $$P(T_{1} = k_{1}, T_{2}-T_{1} = k_{2}, \dots, T_{n}-T_{n-1} = k_{n}) = (1-p)^{k_{1}-1}p \cdots (1-p)^{k_{n}-1}p$$
Then, $\forall i \geq 1$, 
$$P(T_{i}-T_{i-1} = k_{i}) = \sum\limits_{(k_{1}, \dots, k_{i-1})}P(T_{1} = k_{1}, \dots, T_{i}-T_{i-1} = k_{i})$$

But then I don't know what to do...

Comment: "I have shown that $P(T_{1} = k_{1}, T_{2}-T_{1} = k_{2}, \dots, T_{n}-T_{n-1} = k_{n}) = (1-p)^{k_{1}-1}p \cdots (1-p)^{k_{n}-1}p$" ...And this is all one needs to show independence. If you know every $P(Z_1=z_1,\ldots,Z_n=z_n)$, how do you check that $(Z_k)$ is independent already?

Comment: @Did Don't you need to know $P(Z_{i} = z_{i})$ ?

Comment: This value is implied by the collection of $P(Z_1=z_1,\ldots,Z_n=z_n)$.

Comment: @Did It is if they are independent... no ?

Comment: No. Another WP page to check: *Joint probability distribution*.

Comment: @Did I guess you're right but I don't see why.

Comment: @Did Actually what you're saying is what I wrote at the end I believe.

Comment: What you really want to say is that the differences are finite conditional to $T_1<\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\Pr(T_1 = k_1, T_2-T_1 = k_2, \dots, T_n-T_{n-1} = k_n) = (1-p)^{k_1-1}p \cdots (1-p)^{k_n-1}p
$$
First, see if you can show that it is enough to show that for $i=1,\ldots,n$
$$
\Pr(T_i = k_i ) = (1-p)^{k_i}\cdot\text{some constant},
$$
where "constant" means anything that **does not depend on $k_i$**.

Then you have
\begin{align}
\Pr(\,\overbrace{T_1 = k_1}^{i=1}\,) & = \sum_{\underbrace{k_2,\ldots,k_n}_{2\text{ through }n}} \Pr(\,\overbrace{T_1=k_1}^{i=1}\ \&\ \underbrace{T_2=k_2\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ T_n=k_n}_{2\text{ through }n}) \\[10pt]
& = \sum_{\underbrace{k_2,\ldots,k_n}_{2\text{ through }n}} \overbrace{(1-p)^{k_1-1}p}^{i=1} \cdot \underbrace{(1-p)^{k_2-1}p \cdots (1-p)^{k_n-1}p}_{2\text{ through }n} \\[10pt]
& = \overbrace{(1-p)^{k_1-1} p}^{i=1} \sum_{\underbrace{k_2,\ldots,k_n}_{2\text{ through }n}} \underbrace{(1-p)^{k_2-1}p \cdots (1-p)^{k_n-1}p}_{2\text{ through }n} \\ & {}\quad (\text{This last step is possible because the factor that} \\
& {}\qquad \text{was pulled out does not depend on $k_2,\ldots,k_n$.}) \\[10pt]
& = \Big((1-p)^{k_1-1} p \times (\text{something that does not depend on $k_1$}) \Big). \end{align}

It's not hard to show that the constant described as "something that does not depend on $k_1$" is $1$.

By the same argument, you can show that
\begin{align}
\Pr(T_2-T_1 = k_2) & = (1-p)^{k_2-1} p \\
\Pr(T_3-T_2 = k_3) & = (1-p)^{k_3-1} p \\
& \vdots \\ & \vdots
\end{align}

So you get
\begin{align}
& \Pr(T_1 = k_1\ \&\ T_2-T_1 = k_2\ \&\ T_3-T_2 = k_3\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ T_n-T_{n-1}=k_n) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Pr(T_1 = k_1) \cdot \Pr(T_2-T_1 = k_2) \cdot \Pr(T_3-T_2 = k_3) \cdots \Pr(T_n-T_{n-1}=k_n)
\end{align}
and consequently you have independence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I really don't understand. Why $Pr(T_{i} = k_{i})$ is what you said ?

Comment: I really don't believe that's right so downvote sorry

Comment: It is indeed right.  Maybe I'll add a bit more explanation. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks, but you seem to search the distribution of $T_{1}$ when im searching the one of $T_{i}-T_{i-1}$. I know they both have the same distribution but I dont see how what you wrote explains it. I know $T_{1}$ follows a geometric distribution ; in what you wrote, I dont believe it is the case. But I might be totally wrong!

Comment: Btw I know what a "constant " is and how a sum works :) I may suck in probability but at least that I know :)

Comment: I've just updated this to be competely explicit about how one infers independence. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ok I'm stupid. Had the same result you had but didnt notice the constant was 1....... Thanks a lot !!